# Can we trigger snowflake task manually or enable to run at a specific day and time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Can we trigger snowflake task manually or enable to run at a specific day and time?

if the above is not feasible. Any other alternative ideas?

Comment: Yes - did you check the docs? Did you have a problem trying them out? Please let us know

Comment: You schedule it like CRON; anything in CRON you can do you should be able to do in TASKS, like Felipe said, it's in the docs

Comment: @FelipeHoffa    I am getting an error "Invalid schedule was specified. Please refer to the docs on what constitutes a valid schedule.
" while trying a CRON like this 
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK HIST_INSERT
WAREHOUSE = $WH SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 0 17 15 America/Los_Angeles 11/1 ? 2021'

Comment: I am getting an error "Invalid schedule was specified. "2021" is not a recognized time zone. Please specify time zones accepted by the TIMEZONE parameter. " while trying a CRON like this CREATE OR REPLACE TASK HIST_INSERT WAREHOUSE = $WH SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 0 22 15 11 ? 2021'

Answer (score 0):

When using **USING CRON** the following format is accepted:

```
# __________ minute (0-59)
# | ________ hour (0-23)
# | | ______ day of month (1-31, or L)
# | | | ____ month (1-12, JAN-DEC)
# | | | | _ day of week (0-6, SUN-SAT, or L)
# | | | | |
# | | | | |
  * * * * *
```

There is no year option, so something like this would work:

```
'USING CRON 0 9-17 * * SUN America/Los_Angeles'
```

- every hour starting at 9 AM and ending at 5 PM on Sundays (America/Los_Angeles time zone)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to run task manually using
**[EXECUTE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-task.html)**

> **Manually triggers an asynchronous single run of a scheduled task** (either a standalone task or the root task in a task tree) independent of the schedule defined for the task.
>
> A successful run of a root task triggers a cascading run of child tasks in the tree as their precedent task completes, as though the root task had run on its defined schedule.

```
EXECUTE TASK <task_name>;
```